# Formulário de cadastro php SEM banco de dados

Tags: php, jquery, html

Estou aprendendo php e preciso criar um formulário usando apenas html, jquery, ajax e php sem fazer uso de banco de dados. Os dados ineridos devem aparecer em uma tabela abaixo do formulário Fui instruído a fazer usando session, porem, não sei como fazer isso. Alguém tem algum exemplo mesmo que bobinho de como fazer isso ou pode me instruir a como fazer?

Comment: por favor informe com mais detalhes! você quer que os dados sejam inseridos na tabela sem apagar os ja inseridos ou apenas exibi-los e substitui-los quando novos dados forem passados?

Answer (score 6):

Faça o formulário básico em html num arquivo `index.php`:

```
<form method="POST" action="./">
    <input type="text" name="nome" />
    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
</form>
```

Após isso abra a tag php no mesmo arquivo:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // para trabalhar com sessões primeiro, deve inicia-la antes de qualquer coisa

    if(isset($_POST['nome'])) { // se foi enviado formulário
        $_SESSION['NOME'] = $_POST['nome']; // para guardar algo na sessão crie o nome desejado conforme o exemplo e atribuir o valor recebido

        echo $_SESSION['NOME']; // após isso basta imprimir o valor armazenado conforme desejado chamando a variável de acordo com o exemplo
    }
?>
```

É basicamente isso, agora é só replicar os campos seguindo os exemplos, para simular um banco, é só criar um array e ir adicionando o dado recebido a cada envio, mais ou menos assim:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['DADOS'])) {
   $_SESSION['DADOS'] = array(); // se não foi criado ainda a variável DADOS, cria e define como um array
}

array_push($_SESSION['DADOS'], array('nome' => $_POST['nome']....)); // adiciona os dados recebidos no array utilizando a função array_push passando um novo array com esse dados

var_dump($_SESSION['DADOS']); // para testar imprima a variável pra ver como está ficando
```

Espero que esse exemplo básico te ajude a começar, o resto é só pesquisar que você faz facilmente.

Abraço.

Comment: obrigado, ajudou bastante.